# NSIS nsJSON::delete not working as expected

Tags: nsis

I have a json config file to update as part of my NSIS installer. I need to remove a tree based on what the user selects.

Most of what I try is crashing the installer.  I have searched forums, and I have the latest version of the nsJSON plugin (1.1.1.0)

Here is the JSON file.  I'm trying to remove the "Kestrel" tree entirely:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
    }
  },
  "CAD_NIEM_CONNECTION": {
    "CAD_IFP_HOST": "10.1.1.1",
    "CAD_IFP_PORT": 9035
  },
  "NATS": {
    "URL": "nats://localhost:5222",
    "TOPIC": "NIEM_FEED",
    "CLUSTER": "project-dev"
  },
  
  "Kestrel": {
     "Certificates": {
            "Default": {
               "Path": \\https\\WebPoint.pfx
                        }
                   }
             },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "urls": https://*:6001,
  "HTTPS_PORT": "6111"

}
```

Here is the code I'm trying to make work: (with messagebox in there for debug purposes to be sure of when the crash occurs)

```
ClearErrors
nsJSON::Set /file `$INSTDIR\config\NIEMIngestToStream-DEFAULT.appsettings.json`
nsJSON::Set `NATS` `URL` /value `"$NATSURL"`
nsJSON::Set `NATS` `CLUSTER` /value `"$NATSCLUSTER"`
<snip>
${If} $URLPre == "https"
   nsJSON::Set `HTTPS_PORT` /value `"$WEBPORT"`
   nsJSON::Set `urls` /value `https://*:443`
${ElseIf} $URLPre == "http"

   nsJSON::Get /tree Kestrel /exists /end
   Pop $R0
   MessageBox MB_OK "Found Kestrel: $R0"
   nsJSON::Delete /tree "Kestrel" /end
   Pop $R1
   MessageBox MB_OK "Return from Delete Kestrel: $R1"
   nsJSON::Set `urls` /value `http://*:80`
   nsJSON::Set `HTTPS_PORT` /value `""`
${Endif}

nsJSON::Serialize /format /file `$INSTDIR\config\NIEMIngestToStream.appsettings.json`
${If} ${Errors}
  Abort "Unable to update JSON file!"
${EndIf}
```

This causes the installer to crash.  I have tried with and without the /tree argument.

Ideas? Sorry, I'm not a JSON expert.

I have tried syntax found in a few other posts. Most people had issues with older versions of the plugin, but this version supposedly fixed crashes when calling nsJSON::delete

Comment: Feels like a bug, I tried contacting the plug-in author but I would not get my hopes up, have not seen him in years.

Comment: Thanks Anders, I was hoping that was not the case...that I was just doing something incorrectly.    -tcweb

Answer (score 0):

Rather than deleting the tree, I was able to null out values, so that the JSON would still work as expected.

```
${If} $URLPre == "https"
 nsJSON::Set `urls` /value `"https://*:443"`
 nsJSON::Set `HTTPS_PORT` /value `"$WEBPORT"`
 nsJSON::Set `Kestrel` `Certificates` `Default` `Path` /value `"\\https\\WebProgram.pfx"`
${ElseIf} $URLPre == "http"
 nsJSON::Set `urls` /value `"http://*:80"`
 nsJSON::Set `HTTPS_PORT` /value `""`
 nsJSON::Set `Kestrel` `Certificates` `Default` `Path` /value `""`
${EndIf}
```